# tensorflow-gpu stop geting anymore outputs when I was doing the testing part

Tags: python, tensorflow

I met this issue when I was doing the test part(I have finished the training part), it just stop without shows anymore outputs for over 20 minutes, the GPU is running and the CPU usage is very high... The outputs is as follow:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 697865 images belonging to 101 classes.
2020-08-10 22:16:24.785340: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2020-08-10 22:16:25.050899: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2020-08-10 22:16:25.233028: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 1 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2020-08-10 22:16:25.406456: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 2 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:83:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2020-08-10 22:16:25.586879: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 3 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:84:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2020-08-10 22:16:25.588882: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2020-08-10 22:16:26.719130: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-10 22:16:26.719170: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988] 0 1 2 3
2020-08-10 22:16:26.719178: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0: N Y N N
2020-08-10 22:16:26.719181: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 1: Y N N N
2020-08-10 22:16:26.719185: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 2: N N N Y
2020-08-10 22:16:26.719189: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 3: N N Y N
2020-08-10 22:16:26.719882: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-08-10 22:16:26.720283: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-08-10 22:16:26.720567: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-08-10 22:16:26.720884: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 10409 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

Could anybody possibly help me solve this issue?

Here are the package version:

-python:2.7
-tensorflow:1.12.0
-Keras:2.2.4
-CUDA:9.0.176
-cudnn:7.6.5

Comment: you are running out of memory, use smaller batch_size

Comment: the batch_size is equal to 32 now? maybe 8?

Comment: sure batch_size of 8 is fine

Comment: The batch_size of 8 is not ok, I think it is not because of the batchsize but other reason...